# Location of files and usage: apt-get install python-<pkg> vs. pip3 install <pkg>

Tags: python, ubuntu, pip, apt

I found that `sudo apt-get install python-<pkg>` and `sudo pip3 install <pkg>`
install files in different places.

**Is there any way of rendering installation via any of the two options transparent to the user?**

In my particular case, it was not, see below. The binary installed by `apt-get` is removed by `pip3`, so its usage is different.

Byproduct questions are:

In the sequence: 1) apt-get install, 2) pip --upgrade, the second step upgrades version and changes files location. But `apt-get` still thinks it has its original version, at the original location.
**How can this be fixed?**

I meant to install `virtualenv`.
I have just done the following:

1. Install `python-virtualenv`

   ```
   $ sudo apt-get install python-virtualenv
   Reading package lists... Done
   ...
   Setting up virtualenv (15.0.1+ds-3ubuntu1) ...
   ```
2. Check that `pip3` reads `virtualenv`

   ```
   $ sudo pip3 install virtualenv
   The directory '/home/santiago/.cache/pip/http' or its parent directory is not owned by the current user and the cache has been disabled. Please check the permissions and owner of that directory. If executing pip with sudo, you may want sudo's -H flag.                                                                                     
   The directory '/home/santiago/.cache/pip' or its parent directory is not owned by the current user and caching wheels has been disabled. check the permissions and owner of that directory. If executing pip with sudo, you may want sudo's -H flag.                                                                                            
   Requirement already satisfied: virtualenv in /usr/lib/python3/dist-packages
   ```
3. Find which files were installed. These are in `/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages`, and `pip3` understands this.

   ```
   $ ll /usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/virtualenv*
   -rw-r--r-- 1 root root 100655 Nov 30 08:29 /usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/virtualenv.py

   /usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/virtualenv-15.0.1.egg-info:
   total 36
   drwxr-xr-x   2 root root  4096 Apr 22 20:48 ./
   drwxr-xr-x 146 root root 12288 Apr 22 20:48 ../
   -rw-r--r--   1 root root     1 Nov 30 08:29 dependency_links.txt
   -rw-r--r--   1 root root    48 Nov 30 08:29 entry_points.txt
   -rw-r--r--   1 root root     1 Nov 30 08:29 not-zip-safe
   -rw-r--r--   1 root root  3409 Nov 30 08:29 PKG-INFO
   -rw-r--r--   1 root root    11 Nov 30 08:29 top_level.txt
   ```
4. Find the version

   ```
   $ virtualenv --version
   15.0.1
   ```
5. Use `virtualenv`

   ```
   $ virtualenv my_project
   Running virtualenv with interpreter /usr/bin/python2
   New python executable in /home/santiago/my_project/bin/python2
   Also creating executable in /home/santiago/my_project/bin/python
   Installing setuptools, pkg_resources, pip, wheel...done.
   ```

So this was working well.
Now what I did is:

6. Upgrade to the latest version. This had to be done with `pip`, since `apt-get` installed its latest available version.

   ```
   $ sudo pip3 install --upgrade virtualenv                   
   [sudo] password for santiago: 
   The directory '/home/santiago/.cache/pip/http' or its parent directory is not owned by the current user and the cache has been disabled. Please check the permissions and owner of that directory. If executing pip with sudo, you may want sudo's -H flag.
   The directory '/home/santiago/.cache/pip' or its parent directory is not owned by the current user and caching wheels has been disabled. check the permissions and owner of that directory. If executing pip with sudo, you may want sudo's -H flag.
   Collecting virtualenv
   Downloading virtualenv-15.1.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl (1.8MB)
       100% |████████████████████████████████| 1.8MB 781kB/s
   Installing collected packages: virtualenv
   Found existing installation: virtualenv 15.0.1
       Uninstalling virtualenv-15.0.1:
       Successfully uninstalled virtualenv-15.0.1
   Successfully installed virtualenv-15.1.0
   ```
7. Try using `virtualenv`

   ```
   $ virtualenv -p python3 my_project
   bash: /usr/bin/virtualenv: No such file or directory
   ```
8. Find which files were installed. The files installed by `apt-get` are gone.

   ```
   $ ll /usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/virtualenv*
   ls: cannot access '/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/virtualenv*': No such file or directory

   $ ll /usr/bin/virtualenv
   ll /usr/bin/virtualenv
   ```
9. Try recovering what `apt-get` gave.

   ```
   $ sudo apt-get install python-virtualenv             
   Reading package lists... Done
   Building dependency tree       
   Reading state information... Done
   python-virtualenv is already the newest version (15.0.1+ds-3ubuntu1).
   The following packages were automatically installed and are no longer required:
   linux-headers-4.4.0-64 linux-headers-4.4.0-64-generic linux-image-4.4.0-64-generic linux-image-extra-4.4.0-64-generic
   Use 'sudo apt autoremove' to remove them.
   0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 174 not upgraded.
   ```

Answer (score 1):

Generally it's not a good idea to upgrade package installed with the system package manager (`apt` in this case) with `pip` as they will no longer be managed by the system.

`pip` will install into `/usr/local`.  The reason your command was not found in your shell is due to [command hashing](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/86017).  You can run `hash -r` and you'll be able to use `virtualenv ...` again (from `/usr/local/bin/virtualenv`)

The reason `apt` believes that `virtualenv` is still installed is because you have not *uninstalled* it with `apt`.  An upgrade via pip does not update the `dpkg` metadata.  You can verify this with grep:

```
# Note: I'm using xenial, if you're on something ealier the package will
# just be called `python-virtualenv` or `python3-virtualenv`
$ grep -C1 '^Package: virtualenv$' /var/lib/dpkg/status

Package: virtualenv
Status: install ok installed
$ grep -C1 '^Package: python3-virtualenv$' /var/lib/dpkg/status

Package: python3-virtualenv
Status: install ok installed
```

Comment: Comments: 1) *Generally...* : The remaining situation is as good as any installation with pip, so if the newer version is needed, I presume it is ok to `pip`. 2) *`pip`will installl...* : What you mention about hashing is true, but I think it is not the reason why `apt-get` still thinks it has `virtualenv` installed. Actually, it still does so after rehashing. This is likely due to the fact that there are some files left over from `apt-get install`, even if `/usr/bin/virtualenv` is not.

Comment: 1.) I know and I do it too :D -- the argument for using the system package manager is that you'll get potential "stability" and automatic security upgrades -- it's essentially a trade-off. 2) I guess I didn't address why apt thinks it is still installed, I can add this :D

Comment: Updated with information about `dpkg` install state